# Ошибка при попытке соединить таблицы с помощью InnoDB.

Tags: mysql

Уже несколько часов решаю "банальную" проблему с созданием двух простейших таблиц и их соединения с помощью **InnoDB**.

Этого времени хватило,чтобы возненавидеть эту технологию.

И так код:

```
CREATE database thraph;
USE thraph;

CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
  u_id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(u_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `ect` (
  u_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  u_group VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  u_year VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (u_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES userdata(u_id)
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE  = InnoDB;
```

При попытке выполнить сценарии создания таблицы **ect**,постоянно вылетает ошибка

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'thraph.ect' (errno: 150)
-
Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

А если даже удается сформировать запрос и создать таблицу,она не заполняется.
Знаю только:

```
Если оператор MySQL CREATE TABLE выдает ошибку с номером 1005, и в строке сообщения об ошибке присутствует ссылка на ошибку с номером 150, то произошел сбой создания таблицы из-за того, что ограничения внешнего ключа не были сформированы надлежащим образом.
```

Что значит надлежащим образом?Почему нет ничего вразумительного в интернете по этому поводу...Чем этот способ ему не нравиться)

Буду признателен если вы,хотябы частично решите мою проблему.

Comment: Код


    CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
    

и

    FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES user_data(u_id)

Это не очепятка?

Comment: Опечатка при наборе,но она никакого отношения к работоспособности запроса не имеет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При создании внешних ключей типы данных в полях должны быть одинаковыми. Абсолютно.

У вас тип поля в первой таблице

```
  u_id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

а во второй

```
  u_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

Добавьте в первую UNSIGNED и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Верно подмечено =)

Comment: Хочу вас уверить,что я уже проделывал это несколько раз,вы знаете создается таблица,но она в никакую не хочет принимать значения другой DB.Хотя,возможно можно будет извлечь значение id из первой таблицы,и отправить во вторую..?

Comment: И да, вы бы почитали правила создания внешнего ключа. Проблема решилась бы сама собой

Comment: Так и сделаю.В крайнем случае сделаем одну таблицу или скриптик на php.

Answer (score 1):

Вас эти 2 строчки не смущают?

```
PRIMARY KEY (u_id),
FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES userdata(u_id)
```

У вас primary key ссылается на prtimary key.

И если вам необходимо решать задачи а не учиться, в вашем случае - нужно юзать что-то типа mysql workbrench, никак не ручками. Несколько часов решаете проблему?

А вообще запомните - если вы таки работаете ручками и решили сделать foreign key, тогда делайте это вне кода инициализации таблицы, тогда ошибку проще будет выловить (если она будет) и код будет понятнее (если это важно).

Comment: Конечно смушают,даже когда PK были другие значения,выдавало ошибки,но это не главное.Как раз мне необходимо решить задачу и при этом учиться и учиться,чем больше тем лучше.
Хорошо,спасибо за совет.Может вы можете поделиться ссылкой на какую-нибудь хорошую статью по этому поводу.

Comment: Самая лучшая статья это книга. Пока почитайте "Боуман Дж.С., Эмерсон С.Л. Практическое руководство по SQL", как закончите - словите меня где-то, дам еще

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас посмотрим что там.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой в Laravel.

```
$table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Сделал одинаковый тип и длину, использовал `->unsigned()` в обоих значениях. Но ошибка оставалась.  Потом додумался, что значение на которое ссылается `foreign` должно быть `primary key`.

Добавил в Laravel миграцию:

```
$table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned()->primary();
```

и все заработало.